# java how to change this code from finding all true objects to find false

Tags: java, object

I have code that finds all the objects in the list that are true to getranonelectricity and prints them out. How do I change this code so it finds and prints out only false ranonelectricity objects?

```
Transport transports[]=new Transport[10];
transports[0]=Transport1;
transports[1]=Transport2;
transports[2]=Transport3;
transports[3]=Transport3;
transports[4]=Transport4;
transports[5]=Transport5;
transports[6]=Transport6;
transports[7]=Transport7;
transports[8]=Transport8;
transports[9]=Transport9;

for (Transport transportssssss : transports) {
    if (transportssssss instanceof car) {
        if (((car) transportssssss).getranonelectricity()) {
            System.out.println(transportssssss);
```

Comment: just use the not operator. `if(!((car) transportssssss).getranonelectricity())`

Comment: Also, you use Transport3 twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if(((car) transportssssss).getranonelectricity()){
```

to

```
if(!((car) transportssssss).getranonelectricity()){
```

The `!` operator will invert the truth value of any Boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about Logical Operators in Java. For example this: https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/logical-operators-in-java/

You need a "Not" operator.